# SQL Always On Secondary replica limitations

Tags: sql-server, synchronous, alwayson

Can you please clarify how many secondary replica nodes can be in synchronous commit mode in 2012/2014/2016. I know that we can have 4 and 8 secondary replica in 2014 & 2016 respectively. Please let me know the limitation on synchronous committ mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the SQL Server is important but you need to pay attention to the edition, too. There are some major differences between SQL Server editions and I will advice always to refer the official docs for answering such questions by yourself.

In case of Enterprise Edition:

- Up to 4 secondary replicas (SQL Server 2012)
- Up to 8 secondary replicas, including 2 synchronous secondary replicas ([SQL Server 2014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014#High_availability))
- Up to 8 secondary replicas, including 2 synchronous secondary replicas ([SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15))
- Up to 8 secondary replicas, including 2 synchronous secondary replicas ([SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15))
- Up to 8 secondary replicas, including 5 synchronous secondary replicas ([SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSSP))

So, there are different [Availability Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/availability-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15):

- Asynchronous-commit mode
- Synchronous-commit mode
- Configuration only mode

where

> Synchronous-commit mode emphasizes high availability over performance,
>   at the cost of increased transaction latency.

In the `Asynchronous` the primary replica does not wait for any of the secondary replicas to harden the log, while in `Synchronous`, the primary sens confirmation message to the client requesting changes after it receive confirmation from the secondary.

And in Standard edition you have [Basic Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15) which comes with a lot of limitations and 2 synchronous replicas only.